# Linear regression for binary classification - a new classifier

Tags: regression, classification

I am new to classification, but not to regression. I already used regression to fit a linear combination of time varying signals to match two constant signals, -1 and 1, representing their classes.

In order to decide which class the result belongs to, a standard way is to test if the average is positive or negative.

I found a classifier that gives better results, which is computed by comparing the MSE between the prediction and the two constant signals -1 and 1. The smaller MSE decides the class. I am 100% sure other people have used this before (it seems pretty intuitive), but I can't find it anywhere (most likely, I'm not searching for the right words).

Can any of you help me with the name of this classifier and/or where it was used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all: why would you use a suboptimal method where there are *lots* of better ways of doing this? Second, how exactly MSE would work here? "The smaller MSE decides the class" does not make sense since MSE is a *single* value that describes the overall errors of the model, so it us unusable for the purpose.

Comment: I am not talking about the MSE describing the overall performance of the algorithm, but an MSE computed for every time varying prediction (so for every input-output pair), in order to decide the class it belongs to. I hope this is a bit clearer.

Comment: So you are not talking about MSE, but about smaller squared distances. Still, I don't get it, since squared difference between predicted value and -1 will be smaller if the value is < 0 and and it will be smaller to +1 when the value is > 0, so it is the same as if you just took the sign of the value...

Comment: Linear regression with dichotomous dependent variable is equivalent to Fisher's linear discriminant analysis, a classifier.

Comment: Could you walk through an example of how the MSE is computed and compared between the prediction and the two constant signals?

Comment: ttnphns: I did some research on what you said, so thanks for the statement, it was helpful. 

Tim: I am actually talking about the mean squared error between the predicted time series and the time series that is constant -1. And it's not the same thing, because the predicted time series could oscillate above and below 0, in which case computing the MSE would give you a classification of the whole time series, rather than a "real-time" classification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to ttnphns, I learnt this problem is equivalent to Fisher's linear discriminant analysis, a classifier. I realised it's just a matter of choice whether you use MSE or a simple average for class prediction, depending on the application.

Thanks to everyone for their time.

Comment: Fisher's linear discriminant analysis is not based on MSE of class membership predictions.  Its loss function is based on the distance between the two covariance matrices of predictor values for group 1 subjects and predictor values for group 2 subjects.  Your original thoughts about this problem are not based on good statistical principles.